# React native - local-mongoDb - Cannot Read property undefined

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I don't know why this get an error.
I should take from local-mongodb library a new _id of my future new postIt and run new page but in "this.props.onInsertNewPost(idPost);" it get an error (Cannot Read property idPost undefined).
onInsertNewPost call a redux function that set "id" in the initialState.
I tried using binding (this.idPost=this.idPost.bind(this)) anche call idPost() function in componentWillMout, but it get the same problem

```
componentWillMount(){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                db.loadDatabase(err=>{           
                    var obj={
                        year : this.state.year,
                        month : this.state.month,
                        day : this.state.day,
                        houre : this.state.houre,
                        minute : this.state.minute,
                        text : '',
                        isSelected : false,
                        imagesStored : []
                    };
                    db.insert(obj,function(err,doc){

                        let docDoc=JSON.stringify(doc);
                        let parseDoc=JSON.parse(docDoc);

                        console.log(parseDoc._id);

                        idPost=parseDoc._id;
                        this.props.onInsertNewPost(idPost);
                        console.log('create nuovo post');
                        resolve('componentDidMoutnewPostit');
                    });
                });
            },100);
        }); 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem occured because idPost is global. 
if you pass parseDoc._id directly into your onInsertNewPost function it should work.

```
componentWillMount(){
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    db.loadDatabase(err=>{           
                        var obj={
                            year : this.state.year,
                            month : this.state.month,
                            day : this.state.day,
                            houre : this.state.houre,
                            minute : this.state.minute,
                            text : '',
                            isSelected : false,
                            imagesStored : []
                        };
                        db.insert(obj,function(err,doc){
                            let docDoc=JSON.stringify(doc);
                            let parseDoc=JSON.parse(docDoc);
                            console.log(parseDoc._id);
                            this.props.onInsertNewPost(parseDoc._id);
                            console.log('create nuovo post');
                            resolve('componentDidMoutnewPostit');
                        });
                    });
                },100);
            }); 
        };
```